# Plot sinle record in the line graph

Tags: php, pchart

[image]i have the sample code in this location, i want to plot only one year record in the line graph. example: in 2011, Total number of male is 70, i want to plot this into line graph, example screen shot attache in this thread.

```
$DataSet->AddPoint(array("2011"=>7));
```

[Code Ref](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$DataSet->AddPoint(array("2011"=>7, "2012"=>70));
```

Or didn't I understand your question?

Comment: sorry i just updated my thread, i dont have census information for 2012.

Comment: $DataSet->AddPoint(array("2011"=>7));